# Problem with nuget.config - error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[PRIVATE FEED]/nuget/v3/index.json

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I'm having a problem with nuget.config in the following scenario.

I put a policy on the branch to realize a few tasks related restore, build and tests, image bellow.

[image: Image policy branch]

And I'm using the Artifacts Services with many private nuget feeds in my Azure DevOps, image bellow.

[image: Image artifacts]

Well, I've two project in `.net 7`, let's go call **Project A** and **Project B**.

The **Project A** references, through `nuget.config`, to **Project B**.

When I create a Pull Request, the build validation started and throw the following error, image bellow.

[image: Pipeline result from Build Validation]

`D:\a\1\s\[NAME PROJECT].csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[PRIVATE FEED]/nuget/v3/index.json.`

YAML restore task in Azure DevOps Pipeline

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
```

This is my `nuget.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="automatic" value="true" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="[PRIVATE FEED]" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[PRIVATE FEED]/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <apikeys>
    <add key="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[PRIVATE FEED]/nuget/v3/index.json" value="[PRIVATE APIKEY]" />
  </apikeys>
</configuration>
```

I'm already tried some solutions and the error persists.

1. Use APIKEY in `nuget.config`.
2. Use Basic Auth using my personal account in `nuget.config`.
3. Create a service connections in `Azure DevOps -> Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Service Connection`.
4. Set `false` `Azure DevOps -> Project Settings -> Settings -> Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines`

Does someone please help me how to solve this problem and make my restore look for the `nuget.config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check if your credentials for Basic Auth and API Key are correctly configured in nuget.config file
- Make sure the nuget.config file is configured correctly.

Try to provide the complete path to the root of the repository for your nuget.config file in your nuget restore task like below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- cnov-SourceGenerator

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PackageSourceMappingExample/nuget.config'
```

[image]

**My nuget.config file from this sample [repository](https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/tree/main/PackageSourceMappingExample)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!-- Create a repo-specific global packages folder for full security benefit -->
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="globalPackagesFolder" />
  </config>

  <!-- Declare package sources/feeds -->
  <packageSources>
    <!-- To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget-build" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/nuget-build/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

  <!-- Map package ID prefixes and exact package IDs to specific sources target sources, so you always know where your packages come from -->

  <packageSourceMapping>
    <packageSource key="nuget">
      <package pattern="Microsoft.*" />
      <package pattern="Newtonsoft.Json" />
      <package pattern="NuGet.*" />
    </packageSource>
    <packageSource key="nuget-build">
      <package pattern="A" />
      <package pattern="B" />
      <package pattern="C" />
      <package pattern="NuGet.Protocol.VisualStudio" />
    </packageSource>
  </packageSourceMapping>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You helped me a lot! The solution that helped me was the tag `packageSourceMapping`. This solved my problem! Thank you!